# Optimising the Gas Fees on Solana Swap Transactions

Tags: development

Transaction 1: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/21Y7XJFLViPqpWvv4pGXXP6rV276AAQ7WptTXhcuFsdCETZzVkKKydL2EZY7hY1C2ZXwXW8JpuX2PxFTkuudiB5P

Transaction 2: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/58Gb3GMRdnFgN389zw6ftNrizkphRsLcnypttCW1H4u2WQtDi3tG54Eq4kZ5h16MJ5SDkEZ42EVP4rezuNf8gp9D

Transaction 2 uses less compute units than Transaction 1, but still pays like 9x higher fees. What's wrong over here? Can someone please help

Answer (score 1):

Afaik It does not matter how much compute the transaction used, but how much was requested.

The requested amount you can see here:

```
#1 - Compute Budget: Set Compute Unit Limit
Interact With
Compute Budget -ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111  
Instruction Data
Input Accounts
#1 - Units -83361
#2 - Compute Budget: Set Compute Unit Price
Interact With
Compute Budget -ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111  
Instruction Data
03fa9d000000000000
Input Accounts
#1 - Micro Lamports -40442
```

Phantom wallet for example adds fees automatically depending on network congestion.

You can read more about transaction fees here:
https://solana.com/docs/intro/transaction_fees

And here is also a nice video about it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HBBmrkeFX0